# Why did they use CGI in this scene of "Hobbs & Shaw"?

Tags: production, effects, fast-and-furious-franchise, hobbs-and-shaw

At the end of *Hobbs & Shaw* in the scene with the downed helicopter in the rain, it seemed very obvious to me that Jason Statham's character was extremely CGI'd when he was giving his bit of monologue.

I can't think of a reason they would have done this - it was rather jarring. Is there any explanation or reason why they would have used CGI here? Did they just not have Statham available? Did they just make up the scene after the fact?